# How Do I Create Raw String in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++-2010

In C#, I can easily use @"path" to get path that is acceptable to System.IO functions but in C++.NET I am stuck as my path is like "C:\roam..." so it processes "\r" and removes it. So I am not able to get an acceptable path format. Please help.

Comment: Not quite C++0x has support for raw strings. But you probably need VS 2012. Look here for raw string: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use \\ to write a backslash in a C++ character constant, that is "C:\\roam".

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash character:

```
std::string path("C:\\roam");
```